# How to force JS input's 'change' event when value was retyped but not changed?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, html-input

I know there are a lot of similar questions, but I haven't found exactly my case.

Using vanilla JS there is an `input` control in which a user types something. A date as an example (but could be a phone number or anything else with a fixed format). The input data is validated using element's `change` event. So when a user finishes (by pressing `enter` or leaving the control, or submitting, etc.) a validation occurs and if something is wrong an error message is shown.

For a good UX the validation error is cleared once a user starts typing again (i.e. tries to edit the error). This is needed so the user is not confused that data is 'invalid' while he types it because he hasn't finished yet. And when he does finish typing, data is revalidated again. We are not doing real-time validation since it looks confusing ("*am I typing already invalid data??*").

For example, typing unfinished date like `12.12` (without a year) will result in validation error. And when a user starts typing again, the error is cleared until user is finished.

Now consider a case:

1. user types `12.12`;
2. presses `enter`;
3. validation starts and results in an error;
4. users clears input and types `12.12` again;
5. presses `enter`;
6. no validation occurs, since `input` element sees no changes in it's value, hence no `change` event.

So the question is, how to make `input` element believe that data is actually changed so the event is fired again when user finishes editing?

Not sure if emulating `change` event is a good idea (e.g. by dispatching it manually in `blur` or `keypress=enter` or anything similar).

I'm looking for something like an 'optimization' flag for `input` that when disabled will force it to dispatch `change` event regardless of actually changed value. Or something like `invalidateElementValue` that could be called inside element's `input` event.

Comment: You could use the "blur" event to run validation when the element loses focus.

Comment: "_Not sure if emulating `change` event is a good idea_": Why use the [`change` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) in the first place? Based on your description, it seems like it's not the right choice. Are you sure about how it works and which conditions you want to accept as "finalization" states?

Comment: A good user experience either does the validation on (form-)data submit or it silently does a non ennoying background validation wit every occurring [`input`-event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event). Regarding validation, the `change`-event almost always is of no good use.

Comment: @Pointy unfortunately `blur` is not triggered when a user presses `enter` to finish editing without changing focus.

Comment: @jsejcksn `change` is triggered when a user actually finishes editing (changing focus, pressing enter, using auto-fill, etc.).

Comment: @PeterSeliger background validation during typing is not a good UX since it confuses user that data he types right now is already invalid. Which event could you suggest in this case?

Comment: @Yogi I was referring to simple `input` with type `text` and custom input conversion and not `date` type input. Test using latest Chrome.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77469563/how-to-force-js-inputs-change-event-when-value-was-retyped-but-not-changed?noredirect=1#comment136578702_77469563) @KasbolatKumakhov The "etc." is critical here, and an additional criteria is that the `value` actually differs from the last "commit". What you're asking for is a custom implementation for which you haven't defined criteria. You'll have to determine which exact conditions need to be met in order for the validation to occur and every kind of event/action that should trigger the check.

Comment: There is no event that fires according to the same criteria of the [`change` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) except that it disregards the `value` of the element.

Comment: @jsejcksn I get your point. Basically the only difference is that value might be not changed from the last edit. Seems that the only solution in this case is 'emulation'. And perhaps `blur` + `keydown=enter` might be enough.

Comment: You could perform the validation aggressively, and use the `:focus`status of the input to control visibility (with CSS) of the error message block.

Comment: @Pointy that won't work with user pressing `enter` at the end of input and not changing focus.

Comment: Yes it will, because you'll handle that in the "submit" handler; you've got to do work at submit time anyway because you have to check for any fields that are in error and abort the submission.

Comment: @Pointy there are cases when there is no form and hence no 'submit' events (e.g. a filter field in SPA). But of course we do validate data right before sending but that's another case.

Comment: @Yogi that's an interesting link regarding internal flags. Thanks. And for the method - yes, we have done the same thing in our app, 'emulated' `change` event.  Seems to work pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

From some of the OP's and my above comments ...

> A good user experience either does the validation on (form-)data submit or it silently does a non enoying background validation wit every occurring [`input`-event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event). Regarding validation, the `change`-event almost always is of no good use. – Peter Seliger

> > @PeterSeliger background validation during typing is not a good UX since it confuses user that data he types right now is already invalid. Which event could you suggest in this case? – Kasbolat Kumakhov

As I proposed/stated, validation happens at either (form-)data `submit` or with every `input`-event or even at both event types. A good user experience comes with the kind and manner of how one interferes with a user's expectations. Thus, in order to provide the correct information, when hopefully needed, in the most supportive and least annoying way, one has to come up with some complex event- and data-handling. But this does not change anything about the suggested event-types.

**Note**

The beneath posted code is not a suggestion of how the OP's problem has to be solved and validation needs to be done. It is just meant to be a demonstrator in order to show the complexity level needed when it comes to gathering the correct data upon which all UX decisions are going to be made.

```js
function handleInvalidatedRepetition(validationOutput) {
  validationOutput.classList.add('warning');
  validationOutput.value = 'This value has been invalidated before.'
}
function handleFailedValidation(validationRoot, control/*, validationOutput*/) {
  validationRoot.classList.add('validation-failed');
  // validationOutput.value = 'This is an invalid value.';
  control.blur();
}

function clearInvalidatedRepetition(control, validationOutput) {
  const invalidationsLookup = controlRegistry.get(control);
  if (
    invalidationsLookup &&
    !invalidationsLookup.has(control.value) &&
    validationOutput.classList.contains('warning')
  ) {
    validationOutput.classList.remove('warning');

    validationOutput.value = '';
  }
}
function clearValidationStates({ currentTarget: control }) {
  const validationRoot = control.closest('label[data-validation]');
  const validationOutput = validationRoot.querySelector('output');

  const invalidationsLookup = controlRegistry.get(control);

  if (validationRoot.classList.contains('validation-failed')) {
    validationRoot.classList.remove('validation-failed');

    control.value = '';
  }
  clearInvalidatedRepetition(control, validationOutput);
}

function assureNoDotChainedNumbers(evtOrControl) {
  let result;

  const isEvent = ('currentTarget' in evtOrControl);
  const control = isEvent && evtOrControl.currentTarget || evtOrControl;

  const invalidationsLookup = controlRegistry.get(control);
  if (invalidationsLookup) {

    const { value } = control;
    const isValid = !(/\d*(?:\.\d+)+/g).test(value);

    const validationRoot = control.closest('label[data-validation]');
    const validationOutput = validationRoot.querySelector('output');

    clearInvalidatedRepetition(control, validationOutput);

    if (!isEvent) {

      if (!isValid) {
        invalidationsLookup.add(value);

        handleFailedValidation(validationRoot, control, validationOutput);
      }
      result = isValid;

    } else if (!isValid && invalidationsLookup.has(value)) {

      handleInvalidatedRepetition(validationOutput);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

function validateFormData(elmForm) {
  return [...elmForm.elements]
    .filter(control =>
      !(/^(?:fieldset|output)$/).test(control.tagName.toLowerCase())
    )
    .every(control => {
      const validationType =
        control.closest('label[data-validation]')?.dataset.validation ?? '';

      if (!controlRegistry.has(control)) {
        controlRegistry.set(control, new Set);
      }
      return validationLookup[validationType]?.(control) ?? true;
    });
}
function handleFormSubmit(evt) {
  const success = validateFormData(evt.currentTarget);

  if (!success) {
    evt.preventDefault();
  }
  return success;
}


const validationLookup = {
  'no-dot-chained-numbers': assureNoDotChainedNumbers,
};
const eventTypeLookup = {
  'input-text': 'input',
}
const controlRegistry = new WeakMap;


function main() {
  const elmForm = document.querySelector('form');

  [...elmForm.elements]
    .filter(control =>
      !(/^(?:fieldset|output)$/.test(control.tagName.toLowerCase()))
    )
    .forEach(control => {
      const controlName = control.tagName.toLowerCase();
      const controlType = control.type && `-${ control.type }` || '';

      const eventType =
        eventTypeLookup[`${ controlName }${ controlType }`] ?? '';

      const validationType =
        control.closest('label[data-validation]')?.dataset.validation ?? '';

      const validationHandler = validationLookup[validationType];

      if (eventType && validationHandler) {

        control.addEventListener(eventType, validationHandler);
        control.addEventListener('focus', clearValidationStates);
      }
    });

  elmForm.addEventListener('submit', handleFormSubmit);
}
main();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
ul { margin: 4px 0 0 0; }
fieldset { padding: 12px 16px 16px 16px; }
label { padding: 8px 12px 10px 12px; }
code { background-color: #eee; }
.validation-failed {
  outline: 1px dashed red;
  background-color: rgb(255 0 0 / 25%);
}
.warning { color: #ff9000; }
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>No dot chained numbers</legend>

    <label data-validation="no-dot-chained-numbers">
      <span class="label">No dot chained numbers</span>
      <input type="text" placeholder="No dot chained numbers" />
      <output></output>
    </label>

  </fieldset>
</form>

<ul>
  <li>E.g. do type <code>12.45</code>.</li>
  <li>Press <code>&lt;Enter&gt;</code>.</li>
  <li>Focus the <code>input</code> element again.</li>
  <li>Type e.g. another dot chained number sequence.</li>
  <li>
    Maybe repeat the above task sequence by pressing <code>&lt;Enter&gt;</code> again.
  </li>
  <li>Do type input <code>12.45</code> again.</li>
  <li>... Try other stuff; play around ...</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for such detailed post. Unfortunately the provided solution is not comfortable for users since it doesn't provide validation messages at the right time (e.g. after a user finished inputting data with either focus change or pressing `enter`). And also the sample shows that data is cleared after validation (e.g. when inputting `12.45` and pressing `enter` and clicking the field again the input is cleared and no validation happens when `tabbing`). We have decided to go with 'emulation' route.